# How would i create a universal return type in swift?

Tags: swift

say I want to create a function in one of my structures that can take in a string, int, or any type as type, and i want to return the thing i get back based on the type param i pass in wether it be int string or whatever, how would I do that? I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work, the call works but the program crashes when i try to return the value

```
  static func getAny(type: Any, key: String) -> Any? {return data.value(forKey: key) as Any}
```

Comment: What is the type of the data variable in your sample code?

Comment: Userdefaults.standard so its fetching data from save data

Comment: So the reason your crashing is because UserDefault.standards.value(forKey:) returns Any? which you are trying to cast to a Any. By default when you haven't saved anything under that key yet the return value is nil meaning nothing in UserDefaults with that key has been saved yet. if you change as Any to as Any? it won't crash.

Comment: you are right, thanks!

Comment: Don't use `value(forKey:)` with `UserDefaults` unless you have a clear, understood reason to use key-value coding. Use `object(forKey:)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

For the example you described:

```
class MyClasss {

    static let data = UserDefaults.standard

    static func get<Type>(key: String) -> Type? {
        return data.value(forKey: key) as? Type
    }

}

let string = MyClasss.get(key: "stringKey") as String?
let int: Int? = MyClasss.get(key: "intKey")
```

Comment: Use `object(forKey:)`, not `value(forKey:)`.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, I know. I was trying to follow his existing code as closely as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to find a clean way to get and set variables from UserDefaults. This is the way I personally like to do it in my projects.

```
class ApiStorage {
    static var token : String? {
        get {
           return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "bearerToken")
        }
        set {
           UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "bearerToken")
        }
    }
}
```

Then to access UserDefaults it is as simple as

```
var token = ApiStorage.token
```

Or to write to UserDefaults it is as simple as

```
ApiStorage.token = "AUTHTOKEN"
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: The whole question revolves around getting a value from UserDefaults with the type provided in the parameter as a return type instead of Any which is what the above does. Rather then using his getAny function I am providing an alternative method because I have tried to do exactly what he is trying to do in the past and there is no way to pass in a type and have the function dynamically change the return so it is that type.

Comment: The other answer seems to do what is being asked.

Comment: In the other answer the type is just being cast using "as? Type" or "var name: Type" which you can just change to "UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey) as? String" or "var name: String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey)" which is not what sample I provided does.